# difference between seperate xyz and combine xyz?

Tags: volumetrics, shader-nodes

I am trying to make a galaxy with shader nodes, and I am using a gradient texture to distort the rotation on the z-axis. I am wondering why in my setup (see below), the combine XYZ gives me the correct result. Shouldn't the separate XYZ isolate the values for the z-axis so I can only twist along the z-axis?

[image: Without seperate/combine]

[image: seperate]

[image: combine]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance you're using it to define a z-component but leaving the other two values at 0.

This works because the output of *Combine XYZ* is a vector (purple socket) which matches the rotation input of the *Mapping* node.

If you had connected a gray noodle (scalar value) to the rotation socket it would be converted to a vector which sends the same value for each component (x, y, and z).  You'll see the noodle change color if you do this.  Here you converted a color, which is another three component vector, into a scalar value and then did some math.

In other words, you'd use a Separate node to isolate the values of the vector's components to do math with them separately.  A Combine node can pack everything back together into a vector format.

Comment: thank you so much! Is there also a reason why the noodle changes color between the combine xyz and the mapping input? actually both sockets are purple. also the mapping output is purple as well as the noise texture input. but the noodle is grey in between.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to display that way